# What version of Visual Basic introduced static types?

Tags: vb.net, vba, basic

In what version of Visual Basic was the concept of static typing introduced?

Comment: What do you mean by static typing ?

Comment: @SuperPeanut Yeah, after reading for 30 minutes about different variable calssifications, the same question popped into my mind. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce in the first version of VB.Net (Visual Studio 2003) with the use of Option Strict ON compiler statement. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs(v=vs.71).aspx))